# Angular, math function in interpolation / binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angular and I am trying to do this

```
<td>{{(obj.revenue.total / obj.clicks.total).toFixed(2)}}</td>
```

and in the table the result is something like this

`**EPC**
0.60
NaN // returns this, why ?`

I prepared a JSFiddle where you will see this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat='header in headers'>{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='obj in data'>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{obj.clicks.total.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.landing_pages.total_clicks.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.landing_pages.click_through_rate.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.conversions.total.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{(obj.conversions.total / obj.landing_pages.total_clicks)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.conversions.amount.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.cost.total.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{(ob.conversions.amount - obj.cost.total).toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.net.roi.toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.cost.cpc}}</td>
    <td>{{(obj.revenue.total / obj.clicks.total).toFixed(2)}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.cost.ecpc.toFixed(2)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the controller

```
.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.headers = [
    'Traffic Source',
    'Clicks',
    'LP Clicks',
    'LP CTR',
    'Conv',
    'CVR',
    'Rev',
    'Spend',
    'Profit',
    'ROI',
    'CPC',
    'EPC',
    'EPA'
  ];

  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.LoadMyJson = function() {
    angular.forEach(myJson, function(items) {
      $scope.data.push(items)
    })        
  };
  $scope.LoadMyJson();

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5hfwdfs/

see the `td`s CVR, Profit and EPC, are the ones where I need to calculate.

Do you guys have an idea of the issue ?

Comment: You should probably validate that the properties exist and have the types of values you expect before they go into the view.

Comment: you could use filter: fractionSize: 2

Comment: @elclanrs can you give me a piece of code? all of them expect to be numbers, except the `header` `Traffic Source`, that is a name.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that an expression like `(obj.revenue.total / obj.clicks.total).toFixed(2)` can fail in various ways. In the controller I'd check if these properties exist first like `if (obj.revenue && obj.revenue.total && typeof obj.revenue.total === 'number') $scope.revenueTotal = obj.revenue.total` and use that in the view so you know if it displays something is always what you expect, otherwise fail with an error, or gracefully, like display a zero if it is supposed to be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fractionSize filter:

```
<td>{{obj.clicks.total | fractionSize: 2}}</td>
```

You can see the example here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: Ok, it fix it but I am having something wrong, http://jsfiddle.net/kvat53Lv/ , look at `Profit`, there is a 0.00 below the 1st row, why ?

Comment: You have an extra string in your data. It's producing 3 rows, not two as expected.

Comment: "name": "Traffic Source #345"